# Using Twitter bootstrap's img-circle class in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, css

I am working on a project using the twitter's bootstraps css framework. I need to make it work in IE8. The one class am having trouble with is img-circle. Since the border-radius doesn't work in IE8, how do i make it work for the number of instances of border radius in the css file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8