# IE8 rendering problems with h2

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

on a website I am working on I have problems with an rendering issue which I can't figure out.

I've already played with margins, positioning, z-indices and so on to get it away but nothing of that helped.

It only occurs in IE8 (under Windows XP, don`t know if on newer OS also). I know IE8 is a bit deprecated, but because the rest of the page is displaying fine with it I would also like to support it, since some of my visitors may have installed it.

If you take a look at the page you can identify the issue very fast when using IE8:
http://kunden.tommy-computer.at/fsv_noetsch/

Here is what the menu headers look like in modern browsers like FF/Chrome/Opera/IE>8:
[image]

And here is what they look like in IE8 (wrong):

[image]

How can I get rid of it. Please help, can`t figure it out why this happens. Thank you very much !

Comment: [`border-radius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not supported by IE8, it's available from IE9 on.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8

Comment: thx, didn`t know about it. It`s not mandatory for the design so I can live with it ignored in IE8. However if I remove it nothing changes, so I suppose it`s not the reason for the rendering issue ?

Comment: here is a very basic fiddle, but can`t be run in IE8 so not very helpful maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/H3NSv/5/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the new html doctype and I noticed you are also using at least one html 5 element `article`. IE 8 won't recognize that element, or anything related to html 5. You need to use javascript to fix IE by using a script called [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

What this will do is inform IE of the new elements so they can be styled.