# How to apply border radius in IE8 and below IE8 browsers?

Tags: css

I would like to know how to apply border-radius to IE8 and below IE8 browsers.

I know that border-radius is a HTML5 feature and IE8 doesn't support it.

I found that by using .htc we can achieve this but by using htc I am encountering the problem of black background.

I am unable to overcome this problem.

Is there any other way of applying border-radius to IE8? If so can anyone explain me how?

Comment: What kind of problem with background?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Option 1**

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

**Option 2**

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip

**Option 3**

http://css3pie.com/

**Option 4**

http://www.netzgesta.de/corner/

**Option 5**

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8)

EDIT:
**Option 6**

https://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/

Comment: I was able to do by using jquery.corner.js but the edges are not smooth enoughin IE8 and by using css3pie.com the background is becoming black in IE8

Answer (score 7):

Firstly for technical accuracy, `border-radius` is not a HTML5 feature, it's a CSS3 feature.

The best script I've found to render box shadows & rounded corners in older IE versions is [IE-CSS3](http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/). It translates CSS3 syntax into VML (an IE-specific Vector language like SVG) and renders them on screen.

It works a lot better on IE7-8 than on IE6, but does support IE6 as well. I didn't think much to PIE when I used it and found that (like HTC) it wasn't really built to be functional.

Comment: This answer is very standard. CSS3 Pie requires to add z-index and position:relative at some parent div to render properly which affects the complete design terribly. UPvoteD.

Answer (score 3):

`PIE` makes `Internet Explorer 6-9` capable of rendering several of the most useful `CSS3` decoration features

http://css3pie.com/

................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

The border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera, because it is CSS3 property.
so, you could use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)

first check this demo in IE 8 and download it from [here](http://css3pie.com/download/)
write your css rule like this

```
 #myAwesomeElement {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);
}
```

note: added `behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);` in the above rule. within url() you need to specify your PIE.htc file location

Answer (score 0):

As the answer said above, CSS PIE makes things like border-radius and box-shadow work in IE6-IE8: http://css3pie.com/

That said I have still found things to be somewhat flaky when using PIE and now just accept that people using older browsers aren't going to see rounded corners and dropshadows.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement">Rounded Corner Box</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myElement {
    background: #EEE;
    padding: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

PIE.htc file can be downloaded from http://www.css3pie.com