# Border-radius is not working on IE-8

Tags: html, css

border-radius is not working on IE-8 . Need help.
I am using the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Border</title>
<style type="text/css">

.mc-button {
positon:relative;
behavior: url(/PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc);
-webkit-box-shadow: #999 0 0 12px;
border: 1px solid #696;padding: 60px 0;text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
 border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
background: #EEFF99;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input class="mc-button" type="button" value="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

That code i am using for a button. But I am not finding any way to solve. I checked previous questions and as well as answers ,but those solutions are not working.

Comment: dude why you just dont using google ?

Comment: Use `CSS pie` to achieve this for ie

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers

Answer (score 2):

border-radius is not supported by IE8.

To check browser compabitility the http://caniuse.com site is a great resource.