# css rounded div is not working on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this css

```
.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); 
}

.type1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<td style="width:25%; height:15%;">
                         <span runat="server" id ="slSpan" class="circleBase type1">Sl = 320012522121</span>
                     </td>
```

the css is working on firefox 20 and gives me a rounded span.but in IE8 it gives me a rectangle.

help pleae

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support natively rounded corner: You can use a JS polyfill such as [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE8 retro-compatibility.

Alternatively you should use "old method" with backgorund images act like "rounded corners"

Comment: Looks like OP is already using CSS3Pie, see the `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`