# How can i get this style of tabs with pure css in IE without using bottom-radius?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am not a pro- css designer. I need to apply one side rounded and other side slanted style of tabs in my application with pure CSS. There are may solutions available on other sites but they all work for FF and chrome but i need that for IE8..plzz help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) is your best bet. You need to download and reference the file in your CSS but it seems to be the closest to "pure CSS" solution you can get with IE8 + border-radius.