# Should I still use vendor prefixes for border-radius?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

Currently, when I code I use:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
```

But based on my tests, it didn't make any difference with any modern browser ( Chrome 33+, opera 25+, safari 8+). Internet Explorer 8 doesn't supports this property, but the vendor prefixes won't make any difference.

Is there any reason to keep them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius for checking such

Conclusion: No need for adding vendor prefixes for border-radius, as its supported in all major browsers (and IE9+). If you really need border-radius in IE8 check out: [How to apply border radius in IE8 and below IE8 browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers)

But in 99% of cases border-radius is not crucial to a design. Employ the technique of graceful degradation and leave IE8 with square corners

Answer (score 2):

You can also add [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to your page to cover you in a few more cases than just border-radius, as it will add these prefixes for you to be safer.

And for backwards compatibility using CSS3 with older versions of IE there is [PIE](http://css3pie.com) (again not just for border-radius but others) and you can just add this where you need it:

`behavior:url('pie.htc');`