# Borders in IE8 don't look right in right-to-left languages

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, right-to-left

I am currently converting a site to Hebrew which is our first right-to-left language. I am having trouble with an element that has a border on it. We have to support IE8+ and Chrome and Firefox, and it looks fine in every browser except IE8.

Here is how the text should render, with the borders showing up correctly:

[image: correct rendering]

Here is how IE8 renders the borders, no longer making sense in a RTL language:

[image: IE8 rendering]

Does anyone know of any fixes for this? Thanks.

```css
.wrapper {
    width:680px;
    direction:rtl;
}

.phishing-dp {
    border: solid 2px #004B7E;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">ממשלתי הפכה לבלתי יציבה מאוד, ואני מחפש מישהו שיגן על ההון שברשותי עד שהעניין יירגע. אעביר סכום של 850,000 דולר ארה"ב לחשבונך, ואחר כך אבקשך להחזיר 700,000 דולר ארה"ב לחשבוני לאחר התייצבות הממשלה. <span class="phishing-dp">כך יישארו לך 150,000 דולר בתמורה למאמציך</span>.</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant markup and CSS.

Comment: Something pretty comparable to this (I know border-radius doesn't work in IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/54meau2k/

Comment: are you using writing-mode ,bidi-override, direction, (scope css) or dir or else ?

Comment: Jason, here's a tip for next time: Please include the markup right in the question instead of on a third-party site. Questions should always be self-contained and not in part depend on the availability of an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like a border radius issue as IE 8 does not support this.

Please see link below for more ways of hacking the border radius on IE 8

[How to apply border radius in IE8 and below IE8 browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers)

Good Luck

Hope it workds

Comment: I know that IE8 does not support border-radius, it would then ignore it. The issue is with `border` itself in a right-to-left language. I have border-radius on there just for browsers that support it.