# CSS3 PIE call not working

Tags: css, css3pie

I have a site [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/degree-summaries.html)...

View it in Chrome/FF, and you'll see the labels come up with rounded corners. IE8 still showing squared corners.

Here's the CSS where I have my PIE being called...

```
.class-name { background-color: #fff; float:left; margin: 10px 5px 10px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: middle; padding: 15px; width: auto; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bolder; color: #000000; text-align: center; 

    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-toopleft: 20px;

    border-radius: 20px; /*PIE only supports parsed CSS (Shorthand) */
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); }
```

I have the PIE files located in my root folder. I just don't understand what I'm missing here...

Comment: Looks like a relative URL, have you tried url(/PIE.htc) ?

Comment: I've tried the following...  (I placed the files in a directory called /pie)... `url(../pie/PIE.htc)`, `url(/pie/PIE.htc)`, `url(pie/PIE.htc)`, and `url(/PIE.htc)`... Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: It looks like it only supports the shorthand notation. http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#shorthand

Comment: The shorthand worked. Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it only supports the shorthand notation.

> ## Shorthand only
>
> For all CSS properties which PIE parses, only the shorthand versions
> of those properties will be recognized. For example, while
> border-radius is supported, the individual longhand
> border-top-left-radius etc. properties are not.
>
> The reason for this is the same reason URLs are not resolved relative
> to the CSS file (see above): PIE does not have visibility into where
> each style property comes from. If there is both a shorthand and a
> longhand property present, PIE cannot determine the order in which the
> CSS author specified those properties, nor can it determine the
> specificity of the selector for each property. It cannot therefore
> make an informed decision about which property should take precedence.
>
> To avoid making dumb guesses, we have opted to only support shorthand
> properties. Shorthand was chosen over longhand to keep file size small
> and avoid tedious repetition.

Source: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#shorthand

Answer (score 0):

> In 99% of cases border-radius is not crucial to a design. Employ the
>   technique of graceful degradation and leave IE8 with square corners.

quote from [Border Radius for IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8)

Comment: This is going to be an internal corporate site. IE8 is our corporate browser, and the only one we're restricted to right now... so, border-radius is crucial in this design as it will be our only design.