# Style SVG image with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In IE10 and IE11 I must use SVG tag for images.
 
The images are rendered properly, but not their styles *(border-radius)*.
how can I apply the styles *(border-radius)* to the images in IE10+.

```
border-radius: 4px;
```

I need to support all major browsers *(Webkit, Mozilla, IE8+)*

---

**My example**
**http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/3298/**
Here you can see *(In all browsers, I think, except IE10+)*  the images has round-corners, but when you open it in IE10+, it doesn't.

I found some post describing a possible solution.
Here is a live [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/487/)

Comment: Do you just want to add rounded corners to ie10 and ie11?

Comment: @Stefan, sure. Done.

Comment: for IE8+ you have to use something found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland, IE8 - it's such browser where i don't need round-corners :) But i newest browsers - yes

Comment: Yeah what is strange is MSDN blog says that it supports round corners, maybe you need to wrap the img element in a container that uses rounded corners.  Maybe MS does not support it on the img tag itself but on other elements.  That is my best guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/3304/

New code:

```
svg, img {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

I think all that was needed was a rule for svg, and img.

Comment: let me know if I got this wrong I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: thanks :). But here is other problem : http://i.imgur.com/Msw9Dc7.png Need to work with sizes. I this must be javascript as i don't know what image would be in `svg`

Comment: When you say sizes, what do you mean?  would you be able to use max-width? padding? etc?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/3298/ as you can see here author set width, height and viewBox. This values are equal to image size that are also setted. In my case i get first image from collection, so i don't know it size. I need here some othe js that will detect image size and then set it to svg

Comment: would this help??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: ok, now i DO IT! Have some problem with order of executing scripts